# contador ajax e salvar no banco

Tags: ajax

Eu tenho uma lista em uma tabela e coloquei uma coluna para exibir a quantidade de cliques ao ser clicado.

Porém como eu poderia encrimentar o valor que vem do banco e salvar.

Seria por ajax? Se sim, como eu faria:?

Abaixo o código para terem uma idéia.

```css
.wis-numbers>span {
    margin-right: -1px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 500
}
.wis-numbers>span>i {
    line-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-right: 2px
}
.wis-numbers>span.active {
    color: #4CAF50
}
.zmdi-favorite-outline:before{
content:'\f15e'
}
.zmdi-favorite:before{content:'\f15f'}
```

```html
<div class="wis-numbers">                                            
                                                        <span class="active"><i class="zmdi zmdi-favorite"></i> 78</span>
                                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar a sua página que vai receber as requisições do `ajax` para sempre que for requisitada atualizar no banco de dados o valor para mais um e imprimir o valor atualizado.

O comando SQL seria esse:

```
UPDATE suaTabela SET suaColuna = suaColuna + 1;
```

Segue um exemplo de código ajax:

```
let contador = document.getElementById('contador'); //elemento que vai ser clicado.
let contagem = document.getElementById('contagem'); //elemento que mostra a contagem.

contador.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let url = "SuaPaginaAqui";
  ajax.open("POST", url, true);
  ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  ajax.send();
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
      contagem.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Entendi, vou estudar essa sua dica. Obrigada